# I have an SVN repo -- without .svn

Tags: svn, version-control

I have an entirely copy of a large (4gb+) Subversion repository that was copied to another machine without the .svn folders. I have access to the original repository over  a (slow) network connection. Is there any way to use what's in my un-versioned working copy to get back to a working, remote-synched working copy without doing a full checkout and re-downloading all that material?

Comment: Have you access to the source host via means such as rsync or ssh? If so, you might be able to recursively copy the .svn folders from the remote checkout to the local. Other than that, I'm afraid you're probably out of luck...

Comment: you don't have a repo neither working copy. You just have export of some revision (e.g. HEAD, the latest one).